# How to get Keyword search working for a SharePoint list?

Tags: list, search, keyword

Keyword search works perfectly on Picture Library. But I am unable to get it working...am I missing something? Any help with links would be great.

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you using?

Comment: SharePoint 2010 for Internet Sites

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Are you sure your list is Search Enabled?
2. Could you post some of the query used? Here you have an example link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee558338.aspx, but i guess you got beyond this step. Have a look at this article on how to setup a Search scope for your list http://www.bentedder.com/create-a-search-scope-for-a-sharepoint-2010-list-or-library/
3. There is already a free web part on codeplex.com doing that http://listsearch.codeplex.com/

Hope it helps,
C:\Marius

Comment: Thx for info. Will the second link work for Keyword search also? and for third link - Do you know of any solution for SP2010 version?...above is for MOSS2007.

Comment: you could most likely use the 2007 solution on your 2010 or easy upgrade it. and yes, with Keyword search to it would work.